# How can I access files outside of "public_html" with webclient or FTP in C#?

Tags: c#, ftp, hosting, webclient, public-html

I'm just wondering if theres a way to access and read files outside of your "public_html" area of your website/website server with correct and proper credentials, I have previously succeeded in streaming data from file within "public_html" and such but I haven't found a way to access outside of it. Is there possible solution, FTP might be a solution but I've already been working with that and can't find a solution at the moment.

Comment: You can access any file you want, as long as you know the path and it has appropriate permissions.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to read via webclient if it's outside of public_html.

Comment: Oh I just realised theres a handy "copy url to clipboard" on FileZilla, now I know the path, the thing is can you put "ftp://" urls into WebClients?, thank you for the reply!